# Code browsing: How to find out which function a function pointer is pointing to?

Tags: c, vim, callback, function-pointers, cscope

I'm having a huge C code base to browse and understand. I'm doing it using cscope on vim.

But I'm almost clueless when it comes to function pointers as to where they are pointing to. Is there a easy way to find out what callbacks are registered?

Can we find it out using cscope itself ?

Comment: Do you need this for debugging purposes or as part of the application? For debugging purposes, I usually just compare the function pointer address with some map file manually. Some good debuggers might assist with the actual function name but that's kind of rare.

Comment: I need this to add code.

Answer (score -1):

`gd` go local declaration and `gD` go to global declaration. If you want to see the declaration in a new window try: `Ctrl-w gD` for example.

Comment: Hi.. Does it require an entry in .vimrc or cscope_maps ?

Comment: I think you should put this `set path+=**` on you vimrc

Comment: gd just highlights the word.. It's not doing anything related to function pointer